# IIS 500 subcode 128

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

One of my clients is starting to get a lot of 500 errors when accessing ASPX pages. Went in, and see one of the following lines in IIS's logs:

```
2023-01-23 14:05:06 x.x.x.x GET /page.aspx 443 user x.x.x.x useragent https://server/page.aspx 500 128 0 231
```

Reporting a substatus of "128". Doing a search on this, sub-status comes up with nothing. (Actually, that's a lie. Searching comes up with hits explaining "403.5", SSL requiring 128-bits. Which are not relevant.) Anywhere I can dig into to see what IIS is complaining about on this 500.128?

Enabled FRT (Failed Request Tracing), and it appears to be something from the Session module:

```
Step 130 - MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
ModuleName="Session"
Notification="REQUEST_ACQUIRE_STATE"
HttpStatus="500"
HttpReason="Internal Server Error"
HttpSubStatus="128"
ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)"
ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

And true to MS wonderment, 'The operation completed successfully.'

Edit to also add: If the user hits F5 to re-load the page - or if the 500 came from an image link, and they right-click and 'refresh image', it'll load just fine then.

Comment: Please enable FRT to learn more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing That 128 is not very likely to come from IIS itself.

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't sure if FRT would catch that. Will do, thanks @LexLi

Comment: Is that the earliest event in FRT log that recorded 500.128? I will be surprised if the error code comes from a session module.

Comment: You also could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to [capture some logs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4984602-2647-4a76-b8b4-d6155353bd5e/modulename-isapimodule-notification-128-httpstatus-500-httpreason-internal-server-error?forum=iisclassicasp).

Comment: @LexLi - Yup, that's the first instance of it, strangely enough.

Comment: @JasonPan - While I am somewhat familiar with Process Monitor, I will need to look into that. Since there's another website and client on the same machine, I gotta be careful not to take down the other site unless I give 'em enough advance warning. I'll look into that tho, see what I can do. Thanks!